# How can do NRQL(NewRelic) query on json data

Tags: node.js, newrelic, newrelic-platform

This is data  which stored in newRelic.
I want to query on the field **entity** which is inside payload field. How will write the query. Thanks in advance

```
  "results": [
    {
      "events": [
        {
          "appId": 1818553174,
          "appName": "abc",
          "entityGuid": "MTUxMjA2OHxBUE18QVBQTElDQVRJT058MTgxODU1MzE3NA",
          "host": "C02G40VUMD6M",
          "payload": "{\"entity\":{\"id\":\"aa6e9174-5755-48c1-8d55-6054e57b05d2\",\"konelId\":1642835460236,\"sourceID\":null,\"make\":\"Datsun\",\"model\":\"Go+\",\"trim\":\"1.2 T Bensin\",\"trimDetails\":null,\"year\":2014}",
          "realAgentId": 1818556319,
          "tags.account": "STG",
          "tags.accountId": "1512068",
          "tags.guid": "MTUxMjA2OHxBUE",
          "tags.trustedAccountId": "1705222",
          "timestamp": 1643268880422
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the NRQL capture function, which takes a regex - https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/query-your-data/nrql-new-relic-query-language/get-started/nrql-syntax-clauses-functions/#func-capture